# How to filter ListView by requested field on Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Is there any way to create one ListView class which dynamically filters objects with requested field.

or maybe another solutions would be helpful.
Thanks

**viwes.py**

```
class OrderStatusList(ListView):
    template_name = 'app/orders_by_status.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(status=self.kwargs['pk'])


class OrderListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'app/orders_by_customer.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(order__customer=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('order__date_created')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('orders/<pk>', OrderStatusList.as_view(), name="order_status"),
path('orders/customer/<pk>', OrderListView.as_view(), name="order_list"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your URL structure the way you have it, then that's likely the best you can do. Alternatively, if you can tolerate urls with `/orders?status=<status>` or `/orders?customer=<customer_id>`, you can use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html)